# Sending HTML emails that renders correctly in Notes 7

Tags: html, css, language-agnostic, lotus-notes

Does anyone here has any experience on how to send HTML emails that renders correctly on a Lotus Notes Client 7?

My email has a couple of complex CSS files and I tried embedding them on <style> tags, but it doesn't seem to work. The thing is that the email renders perfectly in version 8 and on other email clients.

Any hints or pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an option, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lotus Notes 7 has a terrible HTML engine. Really awful. It's not you.

Here's [some old advice](http://web.archive.org/web/20120422155811/http://www.templatekit.com/lotusnotes1.php) about dealing with it. I also suggest signing up for an email testing service like [Litmus](http://litmusapp.com/email-testing). You're never going to fix the problem, if you can't see the problem.

(In the template I was using, I found the problem was actually in the HTML. It has some sort of bizarre problem with the box model. Wrapping a bunch of elements in DIVs helped)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good chart for various email clients. Unfortunately only Notes 6 is covered at this point, but it gives you a starting point.

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/